# How to use Flask connexion with redis?

Tags: python, flask, redis, connexion

This is my `main.py` file :

```
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis
from controllers.utils import redis_conn # get Redis URL
import connexion

BASE_PATH = "/"

def create_app(*specs):

    _app = connexion.App(__name__)

    for s in specs:
        logger.info("Adding specs {}".format(s))
        _app.add_api(s, validate_responses=True)

    return _app

app = create_app("specs.yaml")

rd_app = app.app
rd_app.config['REDIS_URL'] = redis_conn()

redis_client = FlaskRedis(rd_app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug = True)
```

It seems the Redis has issue and producing this error :

> ImportError: cannot import name 'redis_client' from partially
> initialized module 'main' (most likely due to a circular import)

I can't find any tutorial that use connexion with Redis.
Example of usage `get_fruit.py`:

```
from main import redis_client

def get_fruit(colour, shape, taste):

    hash_name = rd_collections[colour+'_'+shape]
    key_name = '{}:{}'.format(hash_name, taste)
    response_redis = redis_client.get(name=key_name)

    if response_redis is None:

        result = get_fruit_name(colour, shape, taste)

        logger.debug("Updating Redis by adding {}".format(location_id))

        redis_client.set(name=key_name, value=json.dumps(result['fruit_id']), ex=60*60)
        result = OrderedDict({'Result': result})

        return result

    else:
        ...
```

UPDATE:

Attempted as suggested :

```
def create_app(*specs):
    """
    Running apps using connexion
    """
    _app = connexion.App(__name__)

    rd_app = _app.app
    rd_app.config['REDIS_URL'] = redis_conn()
    rd_client = FlaskRedis(rd_app)

    for s in specs:
        logger.info("Adding specs {}".format(s))
        _app.add_api(s, validate_responses=True)

    return _app, rd_client

app, redis_client = create_app("specs.yaml")
```

But still producing the same error.

Comment: You are not initialising FlaskRedis as you should. Follow the Application Factory pattern properly.  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Check in the link I sent how to properly add extensions using the application factory pattern. Long story short, 'redis_client = FlaskRedis(rd_app)' should go inside the create_app.

Comment: I have tried this. I'm getting the same error. I should return `redis_client` from `create_app` right? I can update my answer...

Comment: You are still not doing the app factory pattern correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way, which avoids the circular import, is the following one.

Create a config.py file with your configuration.

```
from controllers.utils import redis_conn # get Redis URL

class MyConfig(object):
    REDIS_URL = redis_conn()
```

Create a wsgi.py file. This will be the starting point of your app.

```
from config import MyConfig
import app_factory

app = app_factory.create_app(MyConfig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        app.run()
```

Create an app_factory.py file with the App Factory pattern:

```
redis_client = FlaskRedis()

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    redis_client.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Create a file routes.py with your routes:

```
from app_factory import redis_client

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return redis_client.get('potato')
```

Comment: Kinda confuse here. in `wsgi.py`, `create_app()` takes ans argument. But in `app_factory.py`, `create_app()` doesnt take any argument

Comment: fixed! hope it makes sense now